# Cannot initialize Direct3D with rastertek tutorial

Tags: directx-11, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with this rastertek tutorial: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11s2tut03.html
The problem happens at the following line of code
`result = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferPtr, NULL, &m_renderTargetView);`
where the result gets the value `E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid.`
I can't figure out what happens. Could someone help me? I use visual studio 2015 community edition, HP Pavilion, Windows 8.1

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the Direct3D Debug layer by passing `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` as the Flags parameter to `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain`:

```
// Create the swap chain, Direct3D device, and Direct3D device context.
result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL,
D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, &featureLevel, 1,
D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain,
&m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
if(FAILED(result))
{
    return false;
}
```

This will enable additional debug information which should provide a hint as to what went wrong before you got `E_INVALIDARG`.

> The Rastertek tutorials are quite old and make extensive use of deprecated APIs. I suggest taking a look at the [Direct3D Game VS Template](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki) and the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) as your first introduction to Direct3D 11. Once you have the modern basics down, you can revisit the Rastertek tutorials and glean any additional information out of them.

*Troubleshooting:* If you get a failure from `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` when you add the debug flag, you may not have the correct debug device installed--although it should have already been handled by the VS 2015 install. See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe this answers my question because what I was essentially looking for is a more or less comprehensive tutorial covering at least basic Direct3D11 technics. The tutoral you've suggested should do the job.